# motion group of projective octave level

Tags: lie-groups

About the motion group of projective octave level: The elliptical motion group is a Lie group of dimension 52, the hyperbolic motion group is a Lie group of dimension 52, and the planar motion group is a Lie group of dimension 36.
What do the corresponding Lie algebras of these 3 groups of movements look like?

Comment: I am not familiar with the terminology "projective octave level". I assume it comes from the study of the octave projective plane. Can you give a little more detail, please?

Answer (score 1):

I also don't know what "projective octave level" means but judging by the names of the groups and their dimensions, here is my guess:

elliptic motion group - real compact group $F_4$

hyperbolic motion group - non-compact and non-split real Lie group of type $F_4$ sometimes denoted $F_4^{-20}$

planar motion group - semi-direct product of $Spin(7)$ and it's 15 dimensional representation that splits into two irreducible pieces: 8 dimensional spinor representation and 7 dimensional defining representation